# Ranking function

Tags: excel

I am looking for some help regarding ranking. My spreadsheet has columns labeled as follows:

```
Tickers
P/E Rate of Change
P/B Rate of Change
Dividend Yield Rate of Change
P/Sales Rate of Change
```

I am looking to come up with a composite ranking that takes into account a tickers relative rank within each rate of change category. I tried this first by creating an additional 4 columns and using the formula as follows:

```
IFERROR(RANK(D4,$D:$D,1),"")
```

I believe this gives me a rank for the corresponding rate of change. However, for those cells that have either a blank or an error I want to use a median in calculating the tickers rank. I was then going to sum the ranks in another column to come up with my final ranking but that doesn't seem to be calculating correctly as I have blank rows returning rankings that don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there.

For one column I would change what you have to

```
=IFERROR(RANK(D4,$D:$D,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
```

Then simply expand to add all ranks together

```
=IFERROR(RANK(A4,$A:$A,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
+IFERROR(RANK(B4,$B:$B,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
+IFERROR(RANK(C4,$C:$C,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
+IFERROR(RANK(D4,$D:$D,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
+IFERROR(RANK(E4,$E:$E,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
```

To avoid potentially large numbers you could use an average (same resulting rank, but potentially easier to understand) by slightly changing the formula to:

```
=(IFERROR(RANK(A4,$A:$A,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
+IFERROR(RANK(B4,$B:$B,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
+IFERROR(RANK(C4,$C:$C,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
+IFERROR(RANK(D4,$D:$D,1),MEDIAN($D:$D))
+IFERROR(RANK(E4,$E:$E,1),MEDIAN($D:$D)))/5
```

Comment: So I did that and I end up with large values. If I want to get this to give me the list of tickers in an 8th column with the lowest score ticker listed 1st how would I do that?

Comment: For your second question (the list of tickers), how many tickers do you want listed? How many tickers do you have overall? Could you just sort by score instead of a separate display?

Comment: I have about 1600 tickers overall and am looking to rank maybe the top 25 for each sector (there are 10 sectors). I am trying to see a breakout at the sector level. I tried the sort function in Excel 2013 but for some reason it doesn't work (maybe because I am using INDEX MATCH referring to a pivot table in order to compile the list of tickers.

Comment: We're getting into "ask another question" territory (helps avoid question creep, and allows others who may have a similar issue find a solution easier). Short answer, I would create a pivot table to summarize the information. That would allow you to sort, and group by sectors